# VS Code extension causes system slowdown with hundreds of rg.exe instances

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Under unclear circumstances, [our VS Code extension](https://github.com/microsoft/sarif-vscode-extension) is causing a dramatic perf degradation due to a huge number of ripgrep (rg.exe) instances. So far I haven't been able to repro this issue, but based on user reports I believe it was introduced by [this change](https://github.com/microsoft/sarif-vscode-extension/pull/462). Can anyone provide some insight into what leads to the execution of rg.exe?

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/164665

https://github.com/microsoft/sarif-vscode-extension/issues/472

https://github.com/microsoft/sarif-vscode-extension/issues/472#issuecomment-1414396307 <- trace logs linked here

*** EDIT
I've seen the two issues cited by 'user' but they did not shed any light on the cause of this behavior.

Comment: Looks like a similar question to [VScode rg process taking all the CPU](/q/75311062). Also [Many rg commands started by vscode that consume 99% of CPUs](/q/65120743)

Comment: *looks at GitHub link. You... work for microsoft and are using Stack Overflow to source answers for a problem with a Microsoft product?

Comment: Yes, which makes questions and answers available to everyone.

Comment: Isn't rg.exe (in VS Code case, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-ripgrep) supposed to be used to _monitor/walk_ into every workspace folder you have? If that PR increased somehow the number of folders you are now monitoring, that may be the reason. I think you should compare this, before and after your change.